# How to implement app lock programmatically in Android

Tags: android, encryption, locking

I have developed an Android app I want to implement password for its use.

1. The password will be constant for all users.
2. People who knew the password can only access the app.
3. Here password is set by me (the app developer).

Now I am confuse on implementing this idea. 
I guess I need a file where I can store encrypted password read the file for validation. But the question is can I ship out my app with a file with encrypted password.
Or shall I use SQLite for this?

Comment: Hey MD might be non sense but thats the reqirment.

Comment: Then go to other site. `This is not your home where you asked anything.`

Comment: And at least know [How to ask question in SO?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: SO is not mine. but we should follow the rules SO.

Comment: Check this [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294774/is-stack-overflow-not-a-forum](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294774/is-stack-overflow-not-a-forum)

Answer (score 1):

What criteria you asked can be done by the following way where you do not need any external file to keep your password in encrypted for safety:

> 1)The password will be constant for all users.

Declare anywhere in your project:

```
public static final String password = "Constant Password which will set by me.";
```

So whenever a user try to use your app, he will enter `the password` and you will match with your `password`.

> 2)People who knew the password can only access the app.

Tell "People" what's the password is:

```
password = "Constant Password which will set by me."
```

> 3) Here password is set by me (the app developer).

Yeah , you already set it! Every time you release a new version, you can change it!

**Disclaimer:** Don't use your "idea"! If any of your user leaks your password, the whole world can access your app!

**Suggestions:** For security purpose use [HASHing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) for Password based login. Give user the freedom to create their own password. You can store every users individual `password` in you database by some [HASH mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

Answer (score 0):

A **warning** for anybody who wants to implement a *password checking mechanism* during the login process: if your decompiled apk leaks the method's name that do the pass checking, it would be easy for attackers to bypass your pass checking by binding a hook to your method and changing the return value. Get yourself familiar with frameworks like [Xposed](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge).

Assuming that our pass checking method name is:

> isPasswordCorrect

and our activity name is:

> PasswordActivity

we can bypass the return value using *Xposed* like below:

```
@Override
public void handleLoadPackage(XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
    final String packageName = "your.package.name";
    if (!lpparam.packageName.equals(packageName)) { return; }

    final String passwordActivity = packageName + ".PasswordActivity";
    final String isPasswordCorrect = "isPasswordCorrect";

    XposedBridge.log("[+] Hooking method");

    findAndHookMethod(passwordActivity, lpparam.classLoader, isPasswordCorrect, String.class, new XC_MethodHook() {
        @Override
        protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
            param.setResult(true);
            XposedBridge.log("[+] Changed result of " + isPasswordCorrect + " to true");
        }
    });
}
```

cheers!